# M2 Fatal error on saving customer account

Tags: magento2, admin, error, fatal-error

Using Magento 2.3.1 we're getting the following error when trying to save any update to a customers account from the back-end...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProduct() on boolean in /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php(30): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product->getProductToValidate(Object(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Interceptor)) #1 /var/www/html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product->beforeValidate(Object(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Interceptor)) #2 /var/www/html/mag2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Q in /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php on line 61
```

Can anyone please help with a way to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix for this myself... for anyone experiencing similar issues it was down to products that had been deleted but still remained in customers saved carts Just setting is_active = 0 on quotes within the quote table where the created date is before products where deleted fixed this problem. Looks like Magento isn't removing deleted products from the quote table.